# Error after uploading a laravel zip file to 000webhost

Tags: laravel-5, web-hosting

I am trying to upload my website zip folder to 000webhost through file manager upload button but each time after 100% upload it tells this error

[image]

what should I do to solve this issue because it is very annoying?

Note: I try to upload a zip folder to 000webhost, my website is a laravel project so it takes up to week to upload through ftp connection so I prefer uploading the project through 000webhost file manager, the zip file is 72 MB.

Comment: Do you have command line access?

Comment: No I dont @Azeame